# How to scrape element after a particular tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I have following html section

```
<td>Hadoop Software
  <strong>:</strong> 1.3.2
</td>
```

I want scrape the text which is present after the strong tag which is 1.3.2, how to do that in scrapy.

I am able to get the text just immediate to opening td tag, but not able to get text coming after strong tag (This is code I am using-

```
rows = response.xpath('//table[contains(@class, "sortable")]/tbody//tr')
for row in rows:
   columns = row.xpath('td')
        version = columns[0].xpath('text()').extract_first()
```

This only gives me output as Hadoop Software

Comment: `//td/text()[2]` - It's the second not the first

Comment: Or after strog tag `//td/strong/following::text()`

Comment: @splash58, //td/text()[2] worked for me. Thanks you very much